# What does раз mean?

Tags: перевод, значения, лексикон

I searched it on yandex images but there doesn't seem to be a really exact definition? Isn't it a noun?

Comment: It can be 1) a counter as a synonym for *один* (***раз**, два, три, четыре, пять, ...*); 2) "once again he did it" = *в который **раз** он это сделал*; 3) "once and for all" = ***раз*** и навсегда*; *What time do I hee him (again)?* = *Который **раз** я его вижу?*

Comment: @Arhad , why wouldn't you put your Comment as an Answer?

Comment: @Michael_1812 Bare translations are not welcomed on Rus.SE, so this question will be probably closed. Therefore, for now, I published just a short comment instead of spending time and effort on a long answer with proper research for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

@Arhad said it right. To his answer, I would only add that on some occasions "раз" is used in the meaning "once":

Раз явился я на работу раньше положенного.

In combination with "однажды", it can mean "once upon a time", though this is a rare situation (and very conversational). This is an example from Vyssotsky's song:

Раз однажды гулял по столице я.

Also, in gymnastics or in the army, your coach or sergeant can command "Раз-два!" оr "Раз-два-три!" to give you rhythm.

Answer (score 3):

To add to all the previous explanations, Раз is one of these multifaceted words in Russian, that as a part of speech, раз can be not only a noun - it depends on its use and meaning, and in time and with practice you will get used to the complexity of using it.

As a **noun**, раз can indicate an instance of previous events, situations, actions, as @Arhad gave examples:

> 2) "once again he did it" = в который раз он это сделал;

or an occurrence,

> 3) "once and for all" = раз и навсегда*; What time do I hee him (again)? = Который раз я его вижу?

or indicate how much something has increased/decreased:

```
 Цены на хлеб выросли в пять раз. - Bread prices have increased five times.
```

as a **pronoun**, it means "one", like in the [above example](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/19481/11408): "Раз-два!" оr "Раз-два-три!" or in a famous children's song:

```
Раз словечко, два словечко - будет песенка. - One - word, two - word, here goes a song.
```

as an **adverb**, раз means once, one day, once upon a time:

```
Раз в крещенский вечерок девушки гадали. (с) Vasily Zhukovsky - Once on Epiphany Eve, girls were fortune-telling.
```

It can also act as a **verb**, indicating unexpected quick action:

```
Ньютон сидел под деревом и раз - ему на голову упало яблоко. Newton was sitting under a tree and poof - an apple fell down onto his head.
```

Раз can also serve as a **conjunction**:

```
Раз ты не хочешь делиться яблоком, то я не поделюсь с тобой шоколадкой. Since you don't want to share your apple with me, I won't share my chocolate with you.
```